# Array[Byte] hashCode() returns different values every time in Scala

Tags: scala

Why does `.hashCode()` return different values for the same input?

```
"ABC".getBytes().hashCode()
```

[image]

Comment: Note that this is technically a question about the JVM, rather than about Scala per se. `Array` is provided directly by the JVM, and so is its `hashCode` method.

Comment: Please, do not post photographs of text. Post text as text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because the `hashCode` of an **Array** doesn't depend on its values *(because it is mutable)* but rather it is unique for each instance, it uses its memory address. So executing the code twice creates tow different arrays that have different memory addresses that have different hash codes.

The solution is to use an immutable structure, like a **List**.

```
"ABC".getBytes().toList.hashCode()
// res: Int = 1984571950

"ABC".getBytes().toList.hashCode()
// res: Int = 1984571950
```

Comment: What happens when you insert an element into an array? Does the hash change?

Comment: @tusharmath No, it doesn't change. As I said, the `hashCode` of an **Array** doesn't depend on its content, just in its memory addresses.